# Calling sort on slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid

In the slickgrid I'm able to set the sort column and it's sort direction using the `grid.SetSortColumn(colName,true/false)`. This only sets the sorting glyph but does no sorting. Is there a way to call the sort event handler. I've defined the sort handler like `grid.onSort.subscribe(function(){});`

Answer (score 12):

The behavior you are observing is correct.

```js
   grid.setSortColumn(columnId, isAsc);
```

only updates the glyph on the sort column.
In your case, you will initially need to sort the data, and then use setSortColumn to update the glyph on sortColumn. You can reuse sorter used in onSort event like this:

```js
   var gridSorter = function(columnField, isAsc, grid, gridData) {
       var sign = isAsc ? 1 : -1;
       var field = columnField
       gridData.sort(function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {
              var value1 = dataRow1[field], value2 = dataRow2[field];
              var result = (value1 == value2) ?  0 :
                         ((value1 > value2 ? 1 : -1)) * sign;
              return result;
       });
       grid.invalidate();
       grid.render();
   }
   var grid = new Slick.Grid($gridContainer, gridData, gridColumns, gridOptions);
 
   //These 2 lines will sort you data & update glyph while loading grid     
   //columnField is field of column you want to sort initially, isAsc - true/false
   gridSorter(columnField, isAsc, grid, gridData);

   //I had the columnField, columnId same else used columnId below
   grid.setSortColumn(columnField, isAsc); 
   
   grid.onSort.subscribe(function(e, args) {
        gridSorter(args.sortCol.field, args.sortAsc, grid, gridData);
   });
```

How I arrived on this solution?

Read comments here. https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/325

Comment: It also has the side effect of adding a sortAsc attribute: `if (col.sortAsc == null) {
          col.sortAsc = true;
        }`

Answer (score 3):

`dataView.fastSort` does the job. You can then use `setSortColumn` to set the sorting glyph.

Answer (score 3):

I have multiple column sort enabled, I had to change the function to pass the correct sort column.

```
grid.onSort.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    gridSorter(**args.sortCols[0].sortCol.field**, **args.sortCols[0].sortAsc**, grid, gridData);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger click event on the column header...which does sorting

I fixed the issue like this...

```
$('.slick-header-columns').children().eq(0).trigger('click'); // for first column
```

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by Mr.Hunts answer but I took a slightly different approach to extend the current  `grid.setSortColumn(columnId, isAsc)` to `grid.setInitialSortColumn(columnId, isAsc)`. This will apply the sort and do everything `grid.setSortColumn` does.

```
    var thisGrid = { //Your grid obj
        columns: , // Your columns object
        grid: , // new Slick.Grid....
    }



    thisGrid.grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) { // ar  var cols = args.sortCols;]
            thisGrid.grid.customSort(args);
        });

    thisGrid.grid.customSort = function (args) {
        var cols = args.sortCols;
        thisGrid.dataView.sort(function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {
                if (cols) {
                    for (var i = 0, l = cols.length; i < l; i++) {
                        var field = cols[i].sortCol.field;
                        var sign = cols[i].sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
                        var value1 = dataRow1[field],
                            value2 = dataRow2[field];
                        var result = (value1 == value2 ? 0 : (value1 > value2 ? 1 : -1)) * sign;
                        if (result != 0) {
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            });
    }
    thisGrid.grid.setInitialSortColumn = function (columnId, ascending) {
        thisGrid.grid.setInitialSortColumns([{
                    columnId: columnId,
                    sortAsc: ascending
                }
            ]);
    };
    thisGrid.grid.setInitialSortColumns = function (cols) {
        sortColumns = cols;
        $.each(sortColumns, function (i, col) {
                var columnIndex = thisGrid.grid.getColumnIndex(col.columnId);
                var column = thisGrid.columns[columnIndex];
                if (col.sortAsc == null) {
                    col.sortAsc = true;
                }
                var args = {
                    grid: thisGrid.grid,
                    multiColumnSort: true,
                    sortCols: [{
                            sortCol: column,
                            sortAsc: col.sortAsc
                        }
                    ]
                }
                thisGrid.grid.setSortColumn(col.columnId, col.sortAsc);
                thisGrid.grid.customSort(args);

            });
    };

    // Trigger 
    thisGrid.grid.setInitialSortColumn("dateDue", true);
```

Comment: What a horrible mess... However this is the most reliable way to get programmatic sorting to work.

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave comments due to reputation, which is where this would be most appropriate, however, my answer is in regard to @Premshankar Tiwari and @Siddharth answers.

I preferred the `dataView.fastSort` option in Siddharth's answer, which works for me in all browsers except IE7 and 8. I didn't test it in IE9 or above. Unfortunately, most on my network run IE7 or 8 due to compatibility issues for legacy applications. BUT, Premshankar's answer works in IE7 and 8.

So, I ended up doing something like this:

```
if (msie > 0) {
    $(".slick-header-columns").children().eq(5).trigger("click");
    $(".slick-header-columns").children().eq(4).trigger("click");
} else {
    dataView.fastSort('process','unit');
}
```

where column index (5) = 'unit' and column index (4) = 'process'. Notice that is the reverse order in `dataView.fastSort` method. I am also using a function that detects IE browser version and assigns it to `msie`.

My only complaint about utilizing the `.trigger` method is that if you set up your grid to dynamically hide/show columns, the indexed feature would potentially sort on unintended columns unless you are only calling it on initialization when hide/show capabilities are present.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [it](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.grid.js#L516) will help you. Looks like SlickGrid is triggering sort to self - so You can trigger it manually if You want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using multicolumn sorting, and loading saved sort data when initialising the grid.

As expected, setSortColumns set the sorting, but didnt actually apply it, and dataView.reSort() or .fastSort() didnt seem to help, regardless of what point in loading I called them 
(I must have missed something, but just couldnt get it to work).

In the end, this worked for me.  I call it immediately after populating my dataView from an ajax call.
Its probably not the slickest, so happy to take feedback on board!

```
function forceResort() {

    var sortColumns = grid.getSortColumns();
    var cols = [];
    $.each(sortColumns, function(index, value) {
        var columnId = value.columnId;
        var sortAsc = value.sortAsc;
        var sortCol = { field: columnId };
        var col = { sortCol: sortCol, sortAsc : sortAsc};
        cols.push(col);
    });

    dataView.sort(function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {

        var sortResult = 0;
        for (var i = 0, l = cols.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (sortResult !== 0) {
                break;
            }

            var field = cols[i].sortCol.field;
            var sign = cols[i].sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
            var value1 = dataRow1[field] || ''; //handle nulls - otherwise erratic sorting
            var value2 = dataRow2[field] || ''; //handle nulls - otherwise erratic sorting

            if ($.inArray(field, dateTypeColumns) > -1) {
                sortResult = compareDates(value1, value2) * sign;
            } else {
                if ($.inArray(field, numericColumns) > -1) {
                    sortResult = compareSimple(value1, value2) * sign;
                } else {
                    sortResult = compareAlphaNumeric(value1, value2) * sign;
                }
            }
        }
        return sortResult;
    });

    grid.invalidate();
    grid.render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more clean solution is not to rely on the arguments to onSort but call getSortColumns instead:

```
  function gridSorter() {
     var scol=grid.getSortColumns();
     if (scol.length===0) return;
     var scolId=scol[0].columnId, asc=scol[0].sortAsc;
     data.sort(function(a, b) {
        var result = a[scolId] > b[scolId] ? 1 : a[scolId] < b[scolId] ? -1 : 0;
        return asc ? result : -result;
     });
     grid.invalidate();
  }
```

Then do:

```
  grid.onSort.subscribe(gridSorter);
```

This will allow to reestablish sorting anytime you want (from example after reloading the data with ajax) simply by calling gridSorter()

Answer (score -1):

If you want multiple column sorting:

```
function grid_sorter(args, grid, dataView) {
    let cols = args.sortCols;
    console.log(cols)
    dataView.sort(function (dataRow1, dataRow2) {
        for (let i = 0, l = cols.length; i < l; i++) {
            let field = cols[i].sortCol.field;
            let sign = cols[i].sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
            let value1 = dataRow1[field], value2 = dataRow2[field];
            let result = (value1 === value2 ? 0 : (value1 > value2 ? 1 : -1)) * sign;
            if (result !== 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    });
    grid.invalidate();
    grid.render();
}

grid_sorter(default_sorting, grid_2, dataView_2);
```

cols is an object like this:

```
- sortCols {
  - length: 2
  - 0 : {
       "sortAsc: true,
       "sortCol": {
           "field: column_id
        }
      }
  - 1: {..}
}
```