# Set a default sort column in SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm using [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) with [DataView](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js) and I'm trying to set a default sort column on my table. Is there a way to trigger the sort or set an option so the column is sorted on load?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the latest version you could do this:

```
grid.setSortColumn("myColId",true); //columnId, ascending
```

You can also set multiple with setSortColumn**s**

Comment: Since I'm using DataView, I don't believe this method will work. I ended up triggering `dataView.sort(comparer, false)` after setting `sortcol = 'myColName'`. (Should I add and accept my own answer?)

Comment: I'm quite mistaken there. I tried it using `dataView.setSortColumn`, which didn't work. But using it on my grid instance worked. As did my solution above.

Comment: @stuart I tried this but all it does is show that sort column as clicked.  It doesn't trigger a sort on my dataView, which is subscribed to the onSort event.  How do I get it to trigger this?

Comment: Hi Nick, did you try my answer (first comment?). Both ended up working for me. Both `sort()` and `setSortColumn()` are trigger events. Make sure they're at the end of your code. If you start your own question with more detail, post the link here and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: @NickRetallack Hey, I am facing the same issue as you pointed. It only changes the glyph on that column but does not trigger onSort. Did you got it working?

Comment: @NickRetallack Got it working. Solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678309/calling-sort-on-slickgrid

Comment: For this to work, you must start with the data sorted properly for the column. This is good practice anyway since it should be done in the select statement if you are using a database.

Answer (score 1):

See my solution here. This applies sort on a column initially without using Dataview.

[Calling sort on slickgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678309/calling-sort-on-slickgrid)

I think it does what you want.

Btw since you are using Dataview. You can also give this a try. But I have not personally tried this.

```
    dataview.reSort()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an interesting thought which worked, and that was to just enable the multi-column header sorting (example-multi-column-sort.html), and then once the grid was loaded simulate a click() on the header row I wanted to be sorted when the grid first appeared ("time" is the name of my column I was sorting). The ID of the column headers is calculated similar to the id for the root div of the grid (at least for now :0) ):

```
        var gridId = $('#myGrid').attr("class");
        gridId = '#'+gridId.replace(" ui-widget","")+'time';
        $(gridId).click();
```

The user then can click whatever other column headers they want, but I just clicked the first one for them.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being my solution just give slick grid the data in the way you want it sorted. then let multisort handle it the rest of the time. still doesn't sold programmatically setting the sort and having the grid update but its quick and easy

```
  this.data = res.data.sort((a, b) => {
            let x = a[config.sortField], y = b[config.sortField];
            return (x == y ? 0 : (x > y ? 1 : -1));//no ===
        })
```